# iOS Download Security

Tags: objective-c, ios, security, pdf

I would like to update my app to support the downloading of PDF documents, but am worried primarily about 2 things:

1: that the user will attempt to use my app to download non-PDF, or virus-riddled items.

2: that said virus riddled-items could infect the device.

I may just be paranoid, as I assume the sandbox would prevent most malware from escaping and screwing with the OS, Kernel or the Lower Level Processes but you can never be too sure.  So my question is twofold: How can I (at least mostly) guarantee the download of only PDF's and do it as securely as possible.

(P.S. the download will be done through any generic website in a webView, not a server seeing as I shudder at the thought of web development).

Based on ozdrgnaDiies' answer, I have found this sample code; which I will be modifying to suit my needs, thank you. http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/server-communication/how-to-download-a-file-only-if-it-has-been-updated

Comment: there are kexts on iOS?  since when?

Comment: So basically you're saying you don't trust the operating system (to be able to sandbox things properly)? Well I wouldn't use my iPhone to run a nuclear power plant either.  If it were me, I'd probably try to do some validation of the PDF file while downloading (i.e. check the first few bytes of PDF data to see if it's really PDF data).

Comment: No, I'm saying I don't trust my users to handle my app appropriately.  The PDF files I intend for them to download is sheet music, and I (speaking as a musician) feel that rampant piracy in the industry means I need safety checks.  I trust apple's sandbox as surely as I trust the SO community, but there are still some holes, and people out there dedicating themselves to exploiting said holes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I've gathered from your question, I assume you want to check if the file you are downloading is a pdf and not anything else? If so, you could check the header of the file to verify it is a pdf.

Example, the first thing in every .pdf (That I have myself) is:

```
%PDF-*.*
```

Where `*.*` is a version(?) number. For example, 1.2, 1.3, 1.5, etc.

Therefore, reading the first 5 characters from a downloaded pdf should result in "%PDF-", otherwise it is not a pdf.

As more examples, the first thing in a jpeg image is:

```
ﾘ・
```

And for an .exe it's:

```
MZ・
```

etc

Comment: Beautiful.  I'll up vote, but I'm more worried about the security bit.  Basically what I'm saying is that the best answer is yours, barring a better answer :P

Answer (score 0):

iOS apps are sandboxed.  Meaning, anything you do within the app should only affect your app.  Unless you attempt to somehow run the downloaded content (which I believe is against the rules for the App Store).  The only thing left would be maliciously crafted PDFs…

I personally don't think it would be a big issue.

Comment: Thank you, but I was looking for more of an "this is how you can find out IF a PDF is malicious" kind of answer.

Comment: There's no real way of figuring out if a PDF was maliciously crafted unless you're in control of the parsing of the file.  Maliciously crafted files (of any type) take advantage of how a program parses its content and handle potential errors or contradictions.  If the code isn't sturdy enough to handle all those weird errors, you potentially have an issue.  Cheers!